# jQuery Autocomplete with arabic words

Tags: php, jquery, html, autocomplete

Hi im trying to use the jquery autocomplete script to use in my site. The i want it to read arabic words and i wonder if there any way to make it work with arabic words. I tried to make it work with mysql but i dosent work. Nothing apperas when i write the arabic letters in the textbox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-6">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "علينا الدهر",
      "ActionScript",
      "Ali",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "علي",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the meta charset to UTF-8 like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Confirmed working for me:

[image]